# Error Handling in Java Task

Tags: java, error-handling

```
public class SomeClass {
    int[] table;    
    int size;

    public SomeClass(int size) {
        this.size = size;    
        table = new int[size];  
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] sizes = {5, 3, -2, 2, 6, -4};
        SomeClass testInst;

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            testInst = new SomeClass(sizes[i]);
            System.out.println("New example size " + testInst.size);
        }   
    }    
}
```

When the constructor SomeClass is called with an argument of -2, a run time error will be generated: NegativeArraySizeException.

I am looking to modify this code so that it behaves more robustly by using try, catch and throw. The constructor should throw an exception but otherwise do nothing when called with a non-positive argument. The main method should catch the exception and print a warning message then continue execution through all six iterations of the loop.
Somebody point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to **throw an exception** (preferably **IllegalArgumentException**) from your constructor of **SomeClass** whenever you get a negative number and handle it in your main method.
Your code should look like;

```
public class SomeClass
{
    int[] table;
    int size;

    public SomeClass(int size)
    {
        if ( size < 0 )
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative numbers not allowed");
        }
        this.size = size;
        table = new int[size];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] sizes = { 5, 3, -2, 2, 6, -4 };
        SomeClass testInst;
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                testInst = new SomeClass(sizes[i]);

                System.out.println("New example size " + testInst.size);
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are operations, like connecting to a remote server using a Socket, which can throw exceptions like SocketException. You need to catch and deal with those exceptions because before you aptempt the connection there is no way to know if it is going to suceed or not.

NegativeArrayException is not like that. Before aptempting to create the array you can know for sure that it is going to fail if you use a negative size.
If the size comes from your code, as is the case, you should fix your code rather than catching that exception.
If it comes from any input you should verify that input and act acordingly before trying to create the array.

Assuming your array of sizes is actually a simplified example of input the way to deal with it would be :

```
public class SomeClass {

    int[] table;
    int size;

    public SomeClass(int size) {
        this.size = size;
        table = new int[size];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] sizes = {5, 3, -2, 2, 6, -4};
        SomeClass testInst;

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            if (sizes[i] < 0) {
                System.out.println("Warning");
            } else {
                testInst = new SomeClass(sizes[i]);
                System.out.println("New example size " + testInst.size);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which gives as output :

```
New example size 5
New example size 3
Warning
New example size 2
New example size 6
Warning
```

Comment: Thank you so much :), tht does answer my problem :).